# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'last_line' referenced be fore assignment

Tags: python

```
elif choices == "B":
            with open("reservation.txt", "r") as file:
                for last_line in file:
                    pass
            if last_line[0] == "#":
                num = 1
            else:
                num = int(last_line[0]) + 1

            name = (input("Enter Name: "))
            date = (input("Enter Date: "))
            time = (input("Enter Time: "))
            adults = int(input("No. of Adult(s): "))
            children = int(input("No. of Children(s): "))
            file = open("reservation.txt", "a")
            file.write(f"{num}\t\t\t{name}\t\t\t{date}\t\t\t{time}\t\t\t{adults}\t\t\t{children}\n")
            file.close()
            print()
```

Comment: Please use 4-space indentation

Comment: What will `last_line` be if the file is empty?

Comment: can you pls elaborate more Sir. thank you or make a correction on the code please

Comment: your indentations seem off

Comment: Sir .and here comes another one  File "E:\3 Python(DICT)\Python\Final_Exam_Reservation.py", line 45, in __init__
    file.write(f"{num}\t\t\t{name}\t\t\t{date}\t\t\t{time}\t\t\t{adults}\t\t\t{children}\n")
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'num' referenced before assignment

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users, and then *ask a question*. It should start with a question word like "how" or "what", and end with a question mark (`?`).

Comment: `last_line` only gets a value if the `for` loop runs at least once. Python can't assume that's the case, therefore `last_line` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open("reservation.txt", "r") as file:
    for last_line in file:
        if last_line[0] == "#":
            num = 1
        else:
            num = int(last_line[0]) + 1

    name = (input("Enter Name: "))
    date = (input("Enter Date: "))
    time = (input("Enter Time: "))
    adults = int(input("No. of Adult(s): "))
    children = int(input("No. of Children(s): "))
    file = open("reservation.txt", "a")
    file.write(f"{num}\t\t\t{name}\t\t\t{date}\t\t\t{time}\t\t\t{adults}\t\t\t{children}\n")
```

Comment: That's not the problem. `with` doesn't have its own scope.

Comment: Tahnk yo uso much Sir Much appreciated

Comment: @AljonAbines most welcome! Consider upvoting and accepting the answer

Comment: here comes anohe one error                                                                                                     init file.write(f"{num}\t\t\t{name}\t\t\t{date}\t\t\t{time}\t\t\t{adults}\t\t\t{children}\n") UnboundLocalError: local variable 'num' referenced before assignment